# with-redefs-fn fails to pick up binding from do-seq?

Tags: clojure

There's something fundamental I'm not getting here.  I expected the following test to pass.  But the 2nd test case "staging"/"staging" fails.  Its as if with-redefs-fn is failing to advance through the test-case instances.  But the logging says everything is fine.  This is confusing.

```
(deftest test-bad-derive-s3-environment
  (testing "variants of props environments"
    (doseq [test-case [{:env "qa1" :expect "qa1"}
                       {:env "dev" :expect "qa1"}
                       {:env "staging" :expect "staging"}]]
      (log/infof "test-case %s" test-case)
      (with-redefs-fn {#'config/environment (fn [] (:env test-case))}
        (let [actual (fs/derive-s3-environment (config/environment))
              _ (log/infof "within redefs :env %s :expect %s" (:env test-case) (:expect test-case))]
          #(is (= actual (:expect test-case))))))))

...

lein test com.climate.test.mapbook.filestore
2016-05-03 16:16:29,353  INFO filestore:288 - test-case {:env "qa1", :expect "qa1"}
2016-05-03 16:16:29,355  INFO EnvConfig:98 - Loading config properties from /export/disk0/wb/etc/env.properties
2016-05-03 16:16:29,357  INFO EnvConfig:98 - Loading config properties from /export/disk0/wb/etc/local.properties
2016-05-03 16:16:29,358  INFO filestore:288 - within redefs :env qa1 :expect qa1
2016-05-03 16:16:29,359  INFO filestore:288 - test-case {:env "staging", :expect "staging"}
2016-05-03 16:16:29,359  INFO filestore:288 - within redefs :env staging :expect staging

lein test :only com.climate.test.mapbook.filestore/test-bad-derive-s3-environment

FAIL in (test-bad-derive-s3-environment) (filestore.clj:29)
variants of props environments
expected: (= actual (:expect test-case))
  actual: (not (= "qa1" "staging"))
2016-05-03 16:16:29,364  INFO filestore:288 - test-case {:env "dev", :expect "qa1"}
2016-05-03 16:16:29,364  INFO filestore:288 - within redefs :env dev :expect qa1
```

Why does my with-redefs-fn fail to redefine the config/environment function in terms of the current test-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notice that your final test instance has an `:expect` of `"qa1"` – the same as the first test instance – so it should actually fail if the code worked as you intended it to; its passing is a symptom of the same problem as the second instance's failing.

Now for the fix – there are two options:

1. Just use `with-redefs` instead of `with-redefs-fn`:

   ```
   (with-redefs [config/environment (fn [] (:env test-case))]
     …)
   ```

   Most of the time this is what you want to do and you can consider `with-redefs-fn` to be an implementation detail behind `with-redefs` – although strictly speaking it does have some utility of its own in that it can redefine dynamically constructed collections of Vars.
2. Use `with-redefs-fn`, but move the inner `let` form inside the anonymous function:

   ```
   (with-redefs-fn {…}
     #(let […]
        (is …)))
   ```

Finally, the reason these work and the version from the question text does not:

`with-redefs-fn` is a function, so at runtime its arguments will be evaluated before it is actually invoked with their runtime values passed in. In particular, the `let` expression that you pass in as the second argument will be evaluated before the redefinition takes place, and so the local called `actual` will get the result of evaluating `(config/environment)` *before* the redefinition as its value, and that value will be installed in the anonymous closure created in the `let`'s body. That closure, however, will then be called with the redefinition in place, and so it will take its notion of the "actual" value from before the redefinition and compare it with the expectation set after the redefinition, resulting in the observed behaviour.

Moving the `let` inside the closure, as in the second approach above, fixes this mismatch problem – the `let` local's value is computed with the redefinition in place and all is well. The first approach using `with-redefs` expands to the second approach.

The log printouts are fine, because they are only concerned with the `doseq` local and never examine any Vars. If they did, they would only see the pre-redefinition values.

Comment: I am now struggling to understand the utility of with-redefs-fn.  The with-redefs works like a champ.

Comment: `with-redefs-fn` is an implementation detail – it exists and is public so that `with-redefs` can use it in its expansion. User code should generally not call it directly. Perhaps I should have mentioned that in the answer!

Comment: Actually I take that back. Most of the time `with-redefs` is more convenient, but `with-redefs-fn` allows one to redef a dynamically created collection of Vars, so it can be useful in some scenarios.